# How do I make each array element to be a divisor of a particular value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am writing this program to find prime numbers between 1 and 100 without using req prime.

Program to find prime numbers between 1 and 100

```
divisors = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]
arr = divisors.to_a
(1..100).each do |value|
  if ((value % (arr.each do |n|) != 0))
    puts "#{value}"
  end
  end
```

What could make each element in array to divide the value as a divisor? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many glitches in your code, and the main is: it has an incorrect syntax and won’t be accepted by ruby parser.

The code below will work, but you should consider reading kinda tutorial on ruby syntax.

```
divisors = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13]
(1..100).each do |value|
  unless divisors.any? { |d| value % d == 0 }
    puts "#{value}"
  end
end
```

The number is prime if and only it has no dividers. Using `unless` in conjunction with [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) we check for the negation of exactly opposite: whether there are no such `d` in `dividers`, so that `value % d` is zero, we are done.

Comment: could you pls explain this statement - unless divisors.any? { |d| value % d == 0 } Sorry, I am new to this..

Comment: Let me repeat my comment here: 15? Hmmm.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it’s a matter of thoughtless copy-paste. Thanks, fixed.